# How to make C# app similar to Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I made a Windows Service that works well except one thing : it can't run EXE program...

My app need to check some data coming from a serial port every 60 seconds, and if a condition match, then run an EXE program.

I tried to use a timer in a C# app like I did in my Windows Service but i can't trigger the event timer_elapsed...

How can I do something similar to Windows Service and be able to run my EXE program ?

Comment: Please edit your post and include what you have already tried and explain, in detail, what  isn't working. Also, please explain your expected result.

Comment: convert the service to an console EXE, then use Task Scheduler to schedule it run.

Comment: The Windows Server is probably running with System Credentials which doesn't have any Environmental properties.  So the location of the exe will be in the same folder and the service exe.  You need to add full path of the executable.  You also may need to set the service to Run As Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your `.EXE` to run on an interval using the Windows Task Scheduler. Then, in the `.EXE` program, have something similar to the below:

```
if(condition is met) 
{
    // EXECUTE PROGRAM HERE
}
else 
{
   // EXIT PROGRAM
}
```

Comment: Task Scheduler seems to be the best option, I still struggle to make it trigger in every situations, but i did not find any better solution.